# Javascript array modify value

Tags: javascript

I have an array as following.

```
var vehicle = new Array();
vehicle.push( { "name": "honda", "value": "civic" } );
vehicle.push( { "name": "toyota", "value": "camry" } );
```

How can I modify this array to change civic to accord?

Comment: What is each item in your _Array_? A generic _Object_. So You're really looking to modify `civic` to `accord` in an _Object_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know the position of the object in the array, then you can simply loop through the array. When you find the value, replace it and exit the loop. If there could be more than one value of "civic" in the array, then leave out the `break;` statement and the loop will change all instances of "civic" to "accord".

```
for(var a = 0, len = vehicle.length; a < len; a++) {
    if(vehicle[a].value === "civic") {
        vehicle[a].value = "accord";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
vehicle[0].value = 'accord';
```

And for the array entirely

```
vehicle.map(function (vehicle) {
   if (vehicle.value === 'civic') {
       vehicle.value = 'accord';
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `vehicle[0].value = "accord"`

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
vehicle[0].value = 'accord';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0, len = vehicle.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (vehicle[i].value === "civic") {
        vehicle[i].value = "accord";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6d7v/1/)

`vehicle[0]['value']='accord';`